# Lenovo 11e Thinkpad Freezing 18.04 kernel 4.15.0

Tags: 18.04, lenovo, freeze, thinkpad

My thinkpad freezes regularly (but randomly) with no warning. The screen just freezes and no mouse movements or keyboard combinations seem to work so it is hard to determine if it is still alive under the hood.... (there are no disk drive lights on this model)

How do I check if it is a display problem?
How do I check if it is a kernel problem (as was being reported in 14.04/16.04)?
I have looked in /var/crash but there is only a shotwell application crash from seven days ago even though it has frozen on me 3 times today.

The only effective action seems to be to hard crash by holding the power button and re-start.

Comment: Have you tried to use SysRq keys to give the kernel direct commands (ie. safely restart or other...)

Comment: I have never heard of SysRq before.... My laptop doesn't have a SysRq key. I have now looked it up and will try to PrtSc in its place the next time it freezes. Also I had forgotten about tty screens and the key combo to get to them so have not tried that either. I will update the job after the next freeze.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in updating this job.... during the crashes there is no response using SysRq keys or trying to switch to a non-GUI terminal screen. still the only thing that seems to work is a long hard power key press for that battery override...

Comment: Alt+SysRQ gets followed by the kernel commands to do something (where you keep the ALT key held during the full sequence).  For newer devices (with fewer keys, esp. no pause/sysrq/break/scrlk multiple extra keys maybe required which usually means Fn+Alt+ *often-unmarked-sysrq-replacement* (as key doesn't exist; it's programmed for the model with a Fn combination that is model specific). REISUB is the most common combination (wikipedia article would be my goto on combinations of letters & their commands)